# Send form with jQuery using keypress()

Tags: php, jquery, forms, keypress

**What I have so far:**

I have a form in PHP that contain the following:

```
<input type="submit" id="0" name="0" value="This button">
<input type="submit" id="1" name="1" value="This button">
<input type="hidden" id="response" name="response" value="150">
```

**The problem:**

I would like to send the response value together with either name=1 or name=0, depending on which button the user submit. However, this should be done using the keyboard letters A and S. If a user press the letter A then the value 0 should be submitted, and if S is pressed then the value 1 should be sent.

**The jQuery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{       
    // listens for any navigation keypress activity
    $(document).keypress(function(e)
    {
        switch(e.which)
        {
            // user presses the "a"
            case 97:    submitViaKeypress("0");
            break;  

            // user presses the "s" key
            case 115:   submitViaKeypress("1");
            break;
        }
    });
});

// shows a given element and hides all others
function submitViaKeypress(element_id)
{
    var response        = $('#response').attr('value');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "initiate.php",
        data: "response=" + response + "&" + element_id + "=" + element_id
    });
}
```

**Goal:**

That "initiate.php receive two POST variables (response and either 0 or 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it sounds like you're trying to do is this:

```
<form id="key_form" action="initiate.php" method="POST">
  <p>Press A or S</p> 
  <input type="hidden" id="key" name="key" value="">
  <input type="hidden" id="response" name="response" value="150">
</form>
```

And

```
$(document).keypress( function( e )
{
  if ( e.which == 97 ) 
  { 
    $("input#key").val( 1 ); 
    $("form#key_form").submit();

  } else if (e.which == 115) 
  { 
    $("input#key").val( 2 ); 
    $("form#key_form").submit();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't respond to either key A or S. Not sure what's wrong although I see that the code looks correct.

Comment: I had a semicolon on the line that starts "data:" Try it now.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. I don't understand what's not working. It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/DTWF6/1/

Comment: The form does not get submitted (when A or S are pressed) and the page where the buttons are does not get reloaded.

Comment: So, the thing about ajax is that information is being sent. It was designed to send information without reloading the page. If you want to add information to the page depending on what key is pressed try $("input#my_hidden_input").val(e.which). If you need to submit the form with javascript try $("#my_form").submit(). Those two functions should be able to do what you need.

Comment: Thank you, this clarified it quite a bit for me. However, I am still not sure how you can actually tell jQuery to submit the form with response/button as POST variables. I might be stupid that don't see it directly but might as well admit it.

Comment: I don't think I understood what your initial intent was. So the ajax call IS sending the information as post variables, but without submitting the form. If you want to use the buttons to send as well you need to do a normal form `<form action="initiate.php" method="POST"><input>...<input></form>` That's how you send information through a regular HTML form. The Ajax is for when you need to send information programatically.

Comment: Ok, let me see if I can explain. I want the key A to send the form using POST with two variables response/key (= A). When the user press S then the form gets send also using POST with two variables response/key (= S). Pressing the key A or S on the keyboard should act as if you pressed the left or right button (submitting the form).

Comment: At this point my friend, you have enough information to build almost any kind of form you could possibly imagine.

Comment: Okey, thanks to your code I managed to modify it and this became the final result: http://pastebin.com/AuVjnb3R - if you can think of a better JS solution please let me know.

Comment: If the goal is simply to output to the screen the keys pressed, then you can do that all within javascript/jQuery. You can get rid of the form and put `<div id="key_pressed"></div>` and instead of `$("#my_form").submit;` you can put `$("key_pressed").html("you pressed A");` Or something along those lines.

Comment: The goal is that you should either be able to press the buttons to choose between A or S and you should be able to press the keys A or S. Both should submit the form and the PHP part is to determine what button or key was pressed.

Comment: make buttons like `<input type="button" id="key_a" vaule="a">` and a function like `function submit_value(value) { $("input#key").val( value ); $("form#key_form").submit(); }` now add click handlers for your new buttons with `$("#key_a").click(function(){ submit_value(1); });` You should be able to figure the rest out.

Comment: That's the problem, the value of both buttons needs to be the same, namely "Press this button".

Comment: `<button id="key">Press this button</button>` You should really try to figure some of this stuff out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would cause jQuery to 'bork' or not... but it looks like you are sending your POST data as GET data.

```
data: "response=" + $('#response').attr('value') + "&key=" + e.which;
```

If you tried to look for these variables in initiate.php using $_POST['response'] I imagine it would not be able to find them unless jQuery knows to magically turn these into post variables.

Does the post variable for 0 or 1 also need to be named 0 or 1?  It is a little strange to change the variable name depending on what the variable is set to.  So for the purpose of this example I am going to change the variable name to be keyPressed. i.e. (keyPressed = 0 or keyPressed = 1).

```
// shows a given element and hides all others
function submitViaKeypress(element_id)
{
   var response = $('#response').attr('value');

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "initiate.php",
      data: {response:response, keyPressed: element_id}
   });
 }
```

Now in your initiate.php file get these variables using the $_POST variable.

```
   $response = $_POST['response'];
   $keyPressed = $_POST['keyPressed'];
```

Comment: It still doesn't submit the form when you press the keys A or S. I don't know why this is but I'm very anxious to find out what the problem is.

Comment: Are you sure that the key press is being recognized for the way you are binding the keypress?

Try alert('key pressed'+ e.which); To make sure it is hearing the key press.

If that is working add an alert() to the start of your submitViaKeyPress() method to make sure the method is being called
alert('submit via key press called with element: '+ element_id);

Comment: I just realized you do not have a success property defined for your ajax post.  What is supposed to happen after the ajax post?  Currently you have not defined any action, so it might appear that nothing is being posted.  Can you describe for me how you expect it should act?

Comment: I want to send the form of the page, with response and keypressed. The form looks like this: <form method="post" action="initiate.php" id="experiment">

Comment: I understand that the success property should alert the user of some feedback, but this is not necessary. All I want the Jquery to do is to send the form with the two POST variables if either keys A or S are pressed.